# Materials in OpenGL-ES affecting other textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, light

I have encountered a problem working with OpenGL-ES (1.0) for android that i'm not able to wrap my head around. I have multiple 3D objects showing through OpenGL-ES that iv'e decided to give some material using:

> gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_... , ... , 0);

For each object i'm drawing I do it something like this:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
*make some adjustment to object*
gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Where "ambient", "diffuse" and "specular" is unique to each object.

The result being that if I use a higher amount of red ambient for example in one material, this will affect the other visible object to also be showing of a little bit in red.

As seen below, two out of three objects to the left is set to get more red ambient in it's material. The material to the right shouldn't be glowing since it's material hasn't but still it does. (picture obviously a bit modified to make it clearer).

[image]

Every object i use has an own material class consisting of information regarding it's material.

Any idea of something iv'e missed or is this how materials acctually work in OpenGL?

(I use a direcitonal light lighting up the whole scene in a direction)

Edit: Just to make this clearer, it's not just ambient colors that affect other objects, if for example an object with a material that recievs 0.2 of all colors in ambient, specular and diffuse comes close to another object with higher values of for example specular, the first object will be much more lightned up as well.

Edit2:

This is the function for drawing all the objects

```
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    Enumeration<String> key = objects.keys();
    while (key.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String k = key.nextElement();

        if(objects.get(k).visible)
        {
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            try
            {
                gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturemanager._tm.get(k.trim())
                    .getTexture()[filter]);
            }
            catch(Exception e){};

            adjust(gl, objects.get(k));
            objects.get(k).draw(gl, 1);
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        }
    }

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

What happens on draw in object class is following

```
    protected void draw(GL10 gl, int filter)
{
    updatePhysics();
    bounds.center.set(this);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, data.vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, data.textureBuffer);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, data.normalBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, data.numIndices,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, data.indicesBuffer);
}
```

**adjust(gl, objects.get(k));** leads to following

```
// rotating, translating and scaling object

    if (obj.blend)
    {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    } else
    {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
    if(obj.enableMaterial)
    {
        obj.getMaterial().enable(gl);
    }
```

and where **obj.getMaterial().enable(gl);** will be the material for the object.
Following is my material class

```
    public void enable(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SHININESS, shininess);
}
```

Where the variables for ambient, diffuse, specular and shininess is set like following

```
    public void setAmbient(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    ambient[0] = r;
    ambient[1] = g;
    ambient[2] = b;
    ambient[3] = a;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some actual complete code samples, that show you drawing an object, in addition to setting the materials (such that someone can follow the flow from start to end)? I don't think there's anything specific to opengl that would cause this unless you're doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Yes i can see that there was lack of information/acctual code in my question. I've edited and added what's happening while drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens if you have an object for which "enableMaterial" is false? Do you ever reset the material? It would seem that it will still be applied for any future objects.

Comment: Acctually, while i was writing an answer to you i managed to describe my problem so that it became obvious to me what the problem really is, it's more complex than i thought but the problem is still all in my code (of course) and in essence you described the root to it. So thanks for that, thumb up!